# MVC 5 Scaffolding still uses old model when the model is updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, scaffolding

I'm using MVC 5, EF 6 Database first and scaffolding

I created an Entity Data Model then generated controller using scaffolding

Then I needed to change some field on the database. I deleted the model which I'd changed (since EF only check for new thing in database, It will not update anything if I don't delete the model)

I deleted the generated files and generated it again, but it still used old data model to generate my controller.

I tried with new model (never generate controller before), didn't work.

Do you have any suggestion? or the way I update the model is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I think, you need to remove & create new views with scaffolding again. Feature of updating scaffold views is not available.

Comment: @AK47 yes, i deleted all view and controller files and created it again. it still used old model, even it had some errors

Comment: Have you updated your EF properly, because when EF is updated old model gets updated automatically.I will suggest you to try one more time to update EF.

Comment: @AK47 I don't know if I updated it properly but my model change exactly with my database changes. I tried to restart visual studio and update model several times too.

Comment: are you able to see changes in model which you have made in database?

Comment: @AK47 Yes, of course. After update the models are synchronized with database. But not the scaffording

Comment: what do u mean by scaffolding? are u talking about only view or controllers also?

Comment: @AK47 both controller and view are generated using old model. For example I have a Student table which has a field: Age. Then I remove that field in database, update model. Now the model no longer has Age property. Next I create a controller using Student. It will generate a controller with CRUD for Student with Age property

Comment: when u update ur model, you need to rebuild your project, then only new model is available.

Comment: @AK47 ahh, it works. thank you so much, I was struggling with this problem everytime I made changes. how come I never think about rebuilding project. once again thank you so much!

Comment: I am putting this comment as answer, please mark it as useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you update your model, you need to rebuild your project, then only new model is available.

Comment: Thank you but I haven't had enough reputation to vote your answer :D

Comment: @Tubc I did it for you :)